# ExpandableListView: Distinct View Groups

Tags: android

I'm trying to subclass an ExpandableListView so that I can add distinct groups.

By distinct groups, I mean that each group contains a different child view type (where all the childeren are the same throughout a group).

That is:

```
Group 1
   TextView 1
   TextView 2
   TextView 3
Group 2
   EditText 1
   EditText 2
   EditText 3
...
```

I tried stacking two ELV ontop of each other in a LinearLayout, however the main behavior I'm trying to obtain (which is the only reason I'm using a ELV in the first place) is lossed: each list becomes independently scrollable, where if a single ELV is used that contains multiple groups, they will all scroll together).

I've already seen the post

[How to add image in expandable List in parent in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1353101/how-to-add-image-in-expandable-list-in-parent-in-android)

However this isn't quite what I'm looking for. This solves the problem for multiple, distinct children within a group:

```
Group 1
    TextView 1
    Image 1
    ----------
    TextView 2
    Image 2
    ...
```

I'm sure with enough time I might be able to figure it out from this, but I wanted to see if anyone has already done it before.

I already implemented my ELV adapter and got everything compiling and running ok, and am now ready to adapt the code to solve this particular problem.

Thank you.

Comment: Here is what I came up with: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14274392/android-expandable-list-view-fragment/14589677#14589677

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there's no support for that from android. one common approach is to make a wrapper object for you list elements. for example, suppose you want to show `Car`s and `Person`s in the list, then you'd do something like

```
class ListElement {
  Car car = null;
  Person person = null;
}
```

at runtime, either `car` or `person` is null. in your implementation of `getView()`, you do something like,

```
ListElement e = getItem(position);
if (e.car != null) {
  // create view for Car
} else if (e.person != null) {
  // create view for Person
} else {
  // error!
}
```

if you use your convert view (which you should), you have to be careful. for example, if convert view was inflated for a `Car`, and you are supposed to be getting a view for a `Person`. a way to handle this is to create an uber view that contains both `Car` and `Person` views, and then you just hide or show the respective part in `getView()`.

```
<FrameLayout ...>
  <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/car_layout" ... />
  <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/person_layout" ... />
</FrameLayout>
```

another way is to have two separate expandable `ListView`s.

Comment: Heh, I was worried the most about convertView b/c I noticed getView checks if its null, and if its not then it just uses whatever convertView is (which could result in a type mismatch as your pointing out). I've also come accrossed getChildType(int groupPos, int childPos), could this be overriden as well to deal with typing ?

Comment: Yes, getChildType() is actually the preferred way. But the solution above works as well.

Comment: Thanks man. I'm going to use your approach first to get it working, then if I'm feeling saucy I'll go for the getChildType glory (heh).

Comment: There is a getGroupType as well. I'm either going to have to do some experimenting, or find an example. I don't think it'll be too difficult to get working.

Comment: Looking at the source for BaseExpandableListAdapter is really helpful: http://androidxref.com/4.0.4/xref/frameworks/base/core/java/android/widget/BaseExpandableListAdapter.java

Comment: The fact that some of BaseExpandableListAdapter's interited methods (getChildType/getGroupType) are from the HeterogeneousExpandableList interface is also indicative of ExpandableListView's support for "distinct" child-types (see doc link above).